# Problem with PowerShell script in Tasks Sheduler Windows Server 2008 R2 - SharePoint Shell Access?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, powershell, sql-server, backup, windows-server

I have a problem with PowerShell script in Tasks Sheduler in Windows Server 2008 R2. I try to run Sheduler Tasks which run batch file which run PowerShell script to Backup Farm and while I choose "Run only when user is logged on" script is working well but when I choose "Run wherther user i slogged on or not" script doesn't work and in Event Viewer I see Event 3351 which say below that Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'

Where is problem? Mayby I should add other user to SharePoint Shell Access?

I use SharePoint Foundarion, SQL Server 2008 and Windows Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you should do:

- Run the task under designated service account e.g. CONTOSO\sp_powershell
- The account needs to have [proper privilages](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/07/06/hey-scripting-guy-tell-me-about-permissions-for-using-windows-powershell-2-0-cmdlets-with-sharepoint-2010.aspx), it needs SharePoint Shell Access (check [Add-SPShellAdmin](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607596.aspx) for more details)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice :) I will inform about progess in my case.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, I created service account for run PowerShell Backup script in Tasks Sheduler and add that account to SharePoint Shell Access and nothing is changed. Should I add this account to every database? I ask because I added only to Config database?

Comment: If you are trying to backup your Content databases then yes, it should have. If you are still having problems try to run PowerShell Shell as a different user (CONTOSO\sp_powershell) and troubleshoot permissions.

Comment: I found solution for my case, I select "Run whether user is logged on or not" , "Run with highest privileges", "Hidden" and I didn't select "do not store password. The tasks will only have access to local resources" but to do this first I had to change Registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa  disabledomaincreds from 1 to 0 because earlier I can't do this. I saw Error message 2147943712.

Now my Task is working good while I'm logon and while I'm logout.